# Disassembly of a very old shower valve

Tags: plumbing

These shower valves have no set screw that holds the handle onto the stem. So I am puzzled as to how to get the handle off so that I can get a wrench into place to unscrew the valve seat and replace the washer. Since there's no shutoff except for the whole house, I do not want to exert much force on any part of this without knowing what I am up to.

[image: the knob in place] [image: the stem] [image: the valve]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: You might be able to get to it with a basin wrench/spanner & not have to remove the tap top at all - example https://www.screwfix.com/p/basin-wrench/13294

Comment: I haven't a clue, but the pipe wrench marks visible on the shaft on the second picture is curious.  Perhaps the porcelain handle screws out, when the shaft is held by a wrench?

Purely a guess.